# Laravel 8 Gate issue iam trying to check condition with different model but there are error show

Tags: laravel, laravel-gate

In my laravel 8 iam define gate but there some problem my gate is accept only one model name is that Admin when i try to check another model name there are error show

here is my authserviceprovider

```
<?php
```

namespace App\Providers;

use App\Models\Admin\Role;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Support\Providers\AuthServiceProvider as ServiceProvider;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Gate;

class AuthServiceProvider extends ServiceProvider
{
/**
* The policy mappings for the application.
*
* @var array
*/
protected $policies = [
// 'App\Models\Model' => 'App\Policies\ModelPolicy',
];

```
/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();
    
    Gate::define('isAdmin', function(Role $role) {

        if ($role->role === 'Admin') {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    });
}
```

}

here is controller

```
 public function index(Role $role)
{
    if (!Gate::allows('isAdmin', $role)) 
    {
        abort(403);
    }

    $users = Admin::with('roles')->get();
    return view('Admin.user.index', compact('users'));
}
```

error message

```
TypeError
```

App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::App\Providers{closure}(): Argument #1 ($role) must be of type App\Models\Admin\Role, App\Models\Admin given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\education\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate.php on line 477
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/users

Comment: Welcome to SO.. please put code not image

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#writing-gates and read the doc by default gate pass login user infomation and your passing `Role::class` data that's the issue

Comment: TypeError
App\Providers\AuthServiceProvider::App\Providers\{closure}(): Argument #1 ($role) must be of type App\Models\Admin\Role, App\Models\Admin given, called in D:\xampp\htdocs\education\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\Access\Gate.php on line 477
http://127.0.0.1:8000/admin/users

Answer (score 0):

[Gate](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#gates) are mostly used to authored login user. if you need to authorise  in any model specific then use [policy](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#creating-policies)

so in  [gate](https://laravel.com/docs/8.x/authorization#gates) we get login `user instance` as call back automatically

so in your case code will be like this

```php
/**
 * Register any authentication / authorization services.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function boot()
{
    $this->registerPolicies();

    Gate::define('isAdmin', function($user) {
       return $user->role->name === 'Admin';
    });
}
```

then in controller

```php
public function index(Role $role)
{
    abort_if(!Gate::allows('isAdmin'));

    $users = Admin::with('roles')->get();
    return view('Admin.user.index', compact('users'));
}
```